# Error while connecting to a region under a profile

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-emr

As per document region is also a parameter of boto.emr.EmrConnection class however, I get the follwoing error while making the connection:
conn = boto.emr.EmrConnection(profile_name='profile_name', region='us-west-2')

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto-2.38.0-py2.7.egg\boto\emr\connection.py", line 68, in **init**
    self.region.endpoint, debug,
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'endpoint'

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is expecting RegionInfo type for region, not string.

So pass `boto.ec2.get_region('us-west-2')` instead of `'us-west-2'`

```
import boto.ec2
boto.emr.EmrConnection(profile_name='profile_name', region=boto.ec2.get_region('us-west-2'))
```

Comment: Or, better yet, simply use the ``connect_to_region`` function, e.g. ``conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-west-2')``

Comment: `boto.emr.EmrConnection(region=boto.ec2.get_region('eu-west-1'))`
didn't work for me.

Comment: @helloV Looking at question it seems like he is trying to connect obtain an EMRConnection ec2 RegionInfo doesn't work.

Comment: @KunalC "seems"? You know he/she accepted the answer? And you "think" he asked a different question? Hmmm.

Answer (score -1):

The method expects RegionInfo so try:

```
import boto.emr
conn = boto.emr.connect_to_region('us-west-1')
```